# Trying to finish off a java code program

Tags: java

I am working on a java code for school and I have spent days on it and I just don't think that I'm heading in the right direction.  Here is the info on the project:

For security-minded professionals, it is important that only the appropriate people gain access to data in a computer system. This is called authentication. Once users gain entry, it is also important that they only see data related to their role in a computer system. This is called authorization. For the zoo, you will develop an authentication system that manages both authentication and authorization. You have been given a credentials file that contains credential information for authorized users. You have also been given three files, one for each role: zookeeper, veterinarian, and admin. Each role file describes the data the particular role should be authorized to access. Create an authentication system that does all of the following:
  Asks the user for a username
  Asks the user for a password
  Converts the password using a message digest five (MD5) hash

It is not required that you write the MD5 from scratch. Use the code located in this document and follow the comments in it to perform this operation.

 Checks the credentials against the valid credentials provided in the credentials file

Use the hashed passwords in the second column; the third column contains the actual passwords for testing and the fourth row contains the
role of each user.

 Limits failed attempts to three before notifying the user and exiting the program

 Gives authenticated users access to the correct role file after successful authentication

The system information stored in the role file should be displayed. For example, if a zookeeper’s credentials is successfully authenticated, then the contents from the zookeeper file will be displayed. If an admin’s credentials is successfully authenticated, then the contents from the admin file will be displayed.
 Allows a user to log out
 Stays on the credential screen until either a successful attempt has been made, three unsuccessful attempts have been made, or a user chooses to exit

Here are the five text files I was given:

admin.txt

Hello, System Admin!

As administrator, you have access to the zoo's main computer system.
  This allows you to monitor users in the system and their roles.

credentials.txt

griffin.keyes 108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f "alphabet soup"  zookeeper
rosario.dawson 3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5 "animal doctor" admin
bernie.gorilla a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b "secret password"   veterinarian
donald.monkey 17b1b7d8a706696ed220bc414f729ad3 "M0nk3y business"    zookeeper
jerome.grizzlybear 3adea92111e6307f8f2aae4721e77900 "grizzly1234"   veterinarian
bruce.grizzlybear 0d107d09f5bbe40cade3de5c71e9e9b7 "letmein" admin

validateCredentials.txt

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package authentication;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author JoeP
 */
public class ValidateCredentials {

    private boolean isValid;
    private String filePath;
    private String credentialsFileName;

    public ValidateCredentials() {
        isValid = false;
        //filePath = "C:\\Users\\joep\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ Authentication\\";
        filePath = "";
        credentialsFileName = "credentials";
    }

    public boolean isCredentialsValid(String userName, String passWord) throws Exception {
        String original = passWord;
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(original.getBytes());
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : digest) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("original:" + original);
        System.out.println("digested:" + sb.toString()); //sb.toString() is what you'll need to compare password strings

        isValid = readDataFiles(userName, sb.toString());

        return isValid;
    }

    public boolean readDataFiles(String userName, String passWord) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fileByteStream1 = null; // File input stream
        FileInputStream fileByteStream2 = null; // File input stream

        Scanner inFS1 = null;                   // Scanner object
        Scanner inFS2 = null;                   // Scanner object

        String textLine = null;
        boolean foundCredentials = false;

        // Try to open file
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Opening file " + credentialsFileName + ".txt");
        fileByteStream1 = new FileInputStream(filePath + "credentials.txt");
        inFS1 = new Scanner(fileByteStream1);

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Reading lines of text.");

        while (inFS1.hasNextLine()) {
            textLine = inFS1.nextLine();
            System.out.println(textLine);

            if (textLine.contains(userName) && textLine.contains(passWord)) {
                foundCredentials = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Done with file, so try to close it
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Closing file " + credentialsFileName + ".txt");

        if (textLine != null) {
            fileByteStream1.close(); // close() may throw IOException if fails
        }

        if (foundCredentials == true) {
            // Try to open file
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Opening file " + userName + ".txt");
            fileByteStream2 = new FileInputStream(filePath + userName + ".txt");
            inFS2 = new Scanner(fileByteStream2);

            System.out.println("");

             while (inFS2.hasNextLine()) {
                textLine = inFS2.nextLine();
                System.out.println(textLine);
            }

            // Done with file, so try to close it
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Closing file " + userName + ".txt");

            if (textLine != null) {
                fileByteStream2.close(); // close() may throw IOException if fails
            }
        }

        return foundCredentials;
    }

}
```

veterinarian.txt

Hello, Veterinarian!

As veterinarian, you have access to all of the animals' health records.  This allows you to view each animal's medical history, current treatments/illnesses (if any), and maintain a vaccination log.

zookeeper.txt

Hello, Zookeeper!

As zookeeper, you have access to all of the animals information and their daily monitoring logs.  This allows you to track their feeding habits, habitat conditions, and general welfare.

Finally, this is the code that I have so far, but when I try to run it in Netbeans it just won't work.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Authentication {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            Scanner scan = null;
            scan = new Scanner(new File("credentials.txt"));
            String credentials[][] = new String[100][4];
            int count = 0;
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
//read name and hased pass
                credentials[count][0] = scan.next();
                credentials[count][1] = scan.next();

//get original pass from file
                String l[] = scan.nextLine().split("\"[ ]+");
                l[0] = l[0].trim();
                l[0] = l[0].replace("\"", "");

                credentials[count][2] = l[0];
                credentials[count][3] = l[1].trim();
                count++;
            }

//ask for user input
            Scanner scanio = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean RUN = true;
            int tries = 0;

            while (RUN) {
                System.out.println("**WELCOME**");
                System.out.println("1) Login");
                System.out.println("2) Exit");

                int ch = Integer.parseInt(scanio.nextLine().trim());

                if (ch == 1) {

//increment number of attempts
                    tries++;

//ask for user and pass
                    System.out.print("Input username:");
                    String username = scanio.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Input password:");
                    String password = scanio.nextLine();

//generate hash
                    MessageDigest md;
                    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                    md.update(password.getBytes());
                    byte[] digest = md.digest();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (byte b : digest) {
                        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
                    }
                    String hPassword = sb.toString();

                    boolean badUser = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        if (username.contentEquals(credentials[i][0])) {
                            if (hPassword.contentEquals(credentials[i][1])) {
//everything looks good. login
                                List<String> data = null;

//check type of user and print
                                switch (credentials[i][3]) {
                                    case "zookeeper":
                                        data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("zookeeper.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
                                        break;
                                    case "admin":
                                        data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("admin.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
                                        break;
                                    case "veterinarian":
                                        data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("veterinarian.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }

                                for (String s : data) {
                                    System.out.println(s);
                                }

//reset tries
                                tries = 0;

//now what to do?
                                System.out.println("\n1) Logout.");
                                System.out.println("2) Exit.");

                                ch = Integer.parseInt(scanio.nextLine().trim());
                                if (ch == 2) {
                                    RUN = false;
                                }

                                badUser = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (badUser) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid Username or password.");
                    }

                } else {
                    RUN = false;
                    break;
                }

//thief alert!!
                if (tries == 3) {
                    RUN = false;
                    System.out.println("Too many invlaid attempts.");
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

PLEASE HELP ME!!!
THANK YOU!!!

Comment: What problem are you having with the code you have written?

Comment: This is the Netbeans error that I am getting:______________________                                                                   java.io.FileNotFoundException: credentials.txt (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
 at Authentication.main(Authentication.java:16)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Ok, I got that error to go away, but now when I run the program it just says "run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds).     I'm not sure why it doesn't prompt me for a username and then password here?

Answer (score 0):

Youa re getting a FileNotFoundException. That is, Netbeans is not finding your credentials.txt file (which possibly is located in a different directory). Make sure your credentials.txt file is located in your Netbeans project directory, as follows:

1) Find your project directory by going to the "Netbeans "Projects" tab, right-clicking in your project folder and selecting "Properties". The "Project folder" will be shown on at the top of the new window displayed (i.e. "C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\YourProjectName").

2) Place your credentials.txt file in that project directory.

3) Re-run your code.

Comment: Ok, I got that error to go away, but now when I run the program it just says "run: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds). I'm not sure why it doesn't prompt me for a username and then password here?

Comment: I believe you are now able to compile your ValidateCredentials class successfully. When it runs there is no prompt so you just see the "build successfully" message. Next you need to have the main method in your Authentication class instantiate and call the ValidateCredentials class to use its isCredentialsValid method. You can instantiate that class using: ValidateCredentials validate = new ValidateCredentials(); and later call its method, such as in : boolean hasValidCredentials = validate.isCredentialsValid(userName, passWord);.

Comment: After adding that code to the Authentication class select that class name in Netbeans, right-click and select "Run". Later, if everything works you may want to refactor Authentication.main() class into multiple methods so that not all your code is in main().